# Is it possible to create n number of objects in java using a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

For example; i'm using this class:

```
Point originOne = new Point(x, y);
```

If i want to create a N number of points (originTwo,originThree...originN); 
can I do it using a for loop like :

```
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){

   }
```

If it's possible; how do i give them different names?

Comment: The situation you're describing is perfect for using arrays, like both answers have provided. Learn more about them here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put them into an array.

```
Point[] origin = new Point[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    origin[i] = new Point(x, y);
}
```

They'd all be using the same `x` and `y` under those conditions.

If you had an array of `x` and `y` you could do it like this:

```
Point[] origin = new Point[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    origin[i] = new Point(x[i], y[i]);
}
```

If you don't like arrays, you could use a list:

```
List<Point> origin = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    origin.add(Point(x[i], y[i]));
}
```

You'd address them as

```
origin.get(i)
```

Comment: Looks like @mastov and I had the same idea :-)

Comment: It's just so simple that there aren't any 2 different ways of doing it ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help @mastov ; its pretty useful for a newbie like me! :)

Answer (score 0):

This will also work if your point will be same, else mastov's solution.

Point[] origin = new Point[n];
Arrays.fill(origin, new Point(x,y));